# How can I add two separate variables from different functions in php?

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in PHP. I am trying to add two variables from two different functions and I am getting an error in that it's not showing anything like the variables is not being passed data out of the function

How can I add these separate variables?

This is my code:

```
function intrestcal()
{
    global $rate , $diff, $principal, $totalint;

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $principal = $_POST['principal'];
        // $intrstRate = $_POST['intrest'] / 100;
        //$tenure = $_POST['tenure'];

        $time = ($diff/30);

        if ($time < 1)
        {
            $newtime = 1;
        }
        $totalint = (($principal * $rate * $newtime)/100);

        //$_SESSION['totalint'] =   $totalint;
        //$mthly = $principal + $totalint;

        echo $totalint;
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['rst']))
    {
        echo '00.00';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '00.00';

    }
} 

function installmentcal()
{
    global $totalint , $principal;

    //  $principal = $_POST['principal'];

    $monthint = $principal + $totalint;
    echo $monthint;

}

<h1 class="subtitle is-5" style="margin-top: -15px;">   Monthly Installments</h1>
<h1 class="title is-4"> $<?php installmentcal()?></h1>
<br>
<h1 class="subtitle is-5" style="margin-top: -15px;">   Total Interest</h1>
<h1 class="title is-3"> $<?php intrestcal();?></h1>
```

I need to add the total interest to the monthly installment

Comment: Can you edit your question so the code is valid? I think a function header is missing at the beginning. Also, can you please specify any error you get? Don't just say: "I am getting an error", but tell us which error and where it occurs.

Comment: OK, I can run your code now, but I get: "Monthly Installments $0" and "Total Interest $00.00", which makes sense because the globals aren't defined. Is that your actual problem, or have you just left the definition of `$rate`, `$diff`, `$principal` and `$totalint` out of the question?

Comment: thats my actual problem

Comment: How can I define those  globals?

Comment: Well, I had a look at your code, but I don't know where to start. You're clearly still learning to code, and that's fine. Let me start with two things. 1. You should not use globals, use [function arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) instead. Here [a link to a more friendly tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/php-user-defined-functions-parameters). 2. Consequently: Do not process the `$_POST` global inside a function that should perform a specific task. Process it outside the function and supply the result as arguments to the function.

Comment: alryt thank you let me  see the tutorial

Comment: if you were write that how would you write it, can you please show me?

Comment: you have to close PHP `?>` after end of second function ;)

Comment: @Toxi i did i just didnt include that, does it have an effect

Comment: if the code above original your php file then yes :) `<?php // ... your php code ... ?><!-- Your HTML can start here -->`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Maybe a stupid question, but why is it a bad idea to reference `$_POST` inside a function? I agree about avoiding `global`, but what's wrong with, e.g. functions that read `$_POST` and return sanitised values?

Comment: You can use `$_POST` inside a function, when the purpose of that function is to process user input. Functions should have a clear singular purpose. It's either to compute something _or_ to process user input. Not both.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just giving you a few tips: 
- do not use globals
- do not use data from the superglobals (such a $_POST, and $_GET) directly, never trust user input.